# Should I store tags in a text field or in separate table?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a table with rows that goes like this:

```
id : path : tags
1 : pictures/pic1.jpg : car bmw
3 : pictures/pic2.jpg : cat animal pussy
4 : pictures/pic3.png : gun
```

Basically it's a gallery where I store paths to pictures in a table so i can list them on a webpage.

The user has an option to search for certain pictures based on keywords he provides. So for example he enters "car gun" into the search field and all pictures which have one of those tags are pulled for him. 
Basic tag search:

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE tags LIKE '%car%' OR tags LIKE '%gun%'
```

Now what I would like to know is, what is the better solution for storing tags? Is it the one described above or this one:

Table pictures:

```
id : path
1 : pictures/pic1.jpg
3 : pictures/pic2.jpg
4 : pictures/pic3.png
```

Table tags:

```
pic_id : tag
1 : car
1 : bmw
4 : gun
..and so on..
```

Tags are stored in a separate table here and each tag has its own row, so during the search I will perform JOIN and search for matches that way.

Which solution is better?

Comment: You might want to read up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: I would go for the "table tags with pic_id", just because it breathes and feels more of a relational database that SQL variants are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding normalization and reusability I would suggest something like this:

Table pictures:

```
id : path
1 : pictures/pic1.jpg
2 : pictures/pic2.jpg
3 : pictures/pic3.png
```

Table tags:

```
tag_id : tag
1 : car
2 : bmw
3 : gun
```

Table tags_pictures:

```
id : tag_id : pic_id
1 : 1 : 1
2 : 2 : 1
3 : 3 : 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The best approach in these cases is to create an intermediate table for the tags per images, establishing a many to many relationship.

Then you will have three tables: one for storing the image with its id and attributes, another one for save the tag and its id, and finally a table which saves the image id and the tag id for all the tags.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about this solution as well, but discarded it since it would required 3 tables and i was afraid it would impacted the performance.

Comment: @user3240613 Unless you have 100.000s of rows, you don't really need to worry about performance

Comment: @user3240613 As kingkero said, the number of rows and tables is not a problem compared with the lack of performance you would get every time you have to parse each set of tags in the other approach.