# insert tags not getting existed tag's id

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I am trying to insert multiple or single tags to a book, I have 3 tables such as books(books record), tags(tags record), books_tag(relation for books and tags), from this [Should I store tags in a text field or in a separate table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684838/should-i-store-tags-in-a-text-field-or-in-separate-table) question I got this idea.

I am first inserting books along with tags, then I am getting the last added ID of the book and trying to insert into books_tag table along with tag ID. My code working perfectly for newly adding tags (which is not existed on tags table) for a book, but if I try to insert existed tag, it is always insert tag ID as 0 (should be existed tag ID from tags table) on books_tag table, Here is my code

```
public function addTag($tags, $book_id)
{
    // Loop tags to insert
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        // insert tags if not existed
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES (:tag) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = :tag');
        // Bind values
        $this->db->bind(':tag', $tag);

        // Execute query
        $this->db->execute();

        // Get lsat id
        $last_tag_id = $this->db->lastId();

        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO books_tag (book_id, tag_id) VALUES (:book_id, :tag_id)');

        // Add tag to books
        $this->db->bind(':book_id', $book_id);
        $this->db->bind('tag_id', $last_tag_id);

        // Execute query
        $this->db->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be a chance that `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag = :tag'` is executed and record of tag is updated/instead of created, in this case i guess `$this->db->lastId()` is empty

Comment: it can be, so is there any solution for this? what if I check the existed tag using php instead ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Yes i guess would be good if first run select query to check tag exists